# dynamic rows generation using KnockoutJS

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have following HTML code which has reference to JavaScript. Code does not show any error but data is not coming up in screen.

I see below line not working

> data-bind='options: AssignResourceView.ResourceViewData

[here is non-working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eu95b2mz/)

I am referring this code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/adNuR/)

```
       <table width='100%'>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th width='25%'>Resource Type</th>
                                <th width='25%'>Resource</th>

                                <th width='10%'> </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody data-bind='foreach: AssignResourceView.GetLines'>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <select data-bind='options: AssignResourceView.ResourceViewData, optionsText: "name", optionsCaption: "Select...", value: "id"'> </select>
                                </td>
                                <td data-bind="with: resourceviews">
                                    <select data-bind='options: resource, optionsText: "name", optionsCaption: "Select...", value: $parent.product'> </select>
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    <a href='#' data-bind='click: $parent.removeLine'>Remove</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

This is my JavaScript code

```
var AssignResourceView = function () {

var AssignResourceViewModel =
   {
       dataFromServer: sampleResourceViews,
       lines: ko.observableArray(),
       ResourceViewLine: {
            resourceviews: ko.observable(),
            resources: ko.observable(),
            selectedresourceviewId :ko.observable(),
            selectedresourceId : ko.observable(),
       },
       addLine: function ()
       {
           AssignResourceViewModel.lines.push(AssignResourceViewModel.ResourceViewLine)
       },
       removeLine: function (line) { AssignResourceViewModel.remove(line) },
       save : function () {
           var dataToSave = $.map(lines(), function (line) {
               return line.resourceviews() ? {
                   resourcename: line.resourceviews().name,
                   resourceid: line.selectedresourceviewId
               } : undefined
           });
           alert("Could now send this to server: " + JSON.stringify(dataToSave));
       },
       LoadVM: {
           Init: function () {
               AssignResourceViewModel.ResourceViewLine.resourceviews.subscribe(function () {
                   AssignResourceViewModel.ResourceViewLine.resources(undefined);
               }),
               AssignResourceViewModel.lines = ko.observableArray([AssignResourceViewModel.ResourceViewLine])
           },
       }
   }

 return {
//main function to initiate the module
Init: function () {
    debugger;
    AssignResourceViewModel.LoadVM.Init();
    var aR = document.getElementById("assignresourcediv");
    ko.applyBindings(AssignResourceViewModel, aR);

},
GetLines:function(){
    AssignResourceViewModel.lines();
},
AddLine: function () {
    debugger;
    AssignResourceViewModel.addLine();
},
RemoveLine: function () {
    AssignResourceViewModel.removeLine();
},
Save:function(){
    AssignResourceViewModel.save();
},
ResourceViewData:function(){
    AssignResourceViewModel.dataFromServer;
},
Model: AssignResourceViewModel
 };
}();
```

My JSON Sample

```
 var sampleResourceViews = [

 {
  "resource": [
   {
       "name": "deepak",
       "id": 1
   },
   {
       "name": "raju",
       "id": 2
   }
  ],
  "name": "Vallet",
  "id":1
},
{
  "resource": [
    {
        "name": "deepak",
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "raju",
        "id": 2
    }
  ],
  "name": "Service Specialist",
  "id": 2
},
{
  "resource": [
   {
       "name": "deepak",
       "id": 1
   },
   {
       "name": "raju",
       "id": 2
   }
  ],
  "name": "Sales Specialist",
  "id": 3
},
{
  "resource": [
   {
       "name": "deepak",
       "id": 1
   },
   {
       "name": "raju",
       "id": 2
   }
  ],
  "name": "Delivery Specialist",
  "id": 4
 }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spotted a few things wrong with your fiddle...

- missing KO itself
- Nothing to call init of your module?
- Incorrect bindings

I've made a few tweaks, and got some of it working:

http://jsfiddle.net/sifriday/eu95b2mz/2/

Notably:

1 Added KO as an external resource

2 Called the init method like so -

```
arv = AssignResourceView()
arv.Init()
```

3 Adjusted the binding syntax to, eg:

```
<tbody data-bind='foreach: lines'>
```

Hopefully that'll help you see how to fix the rest. I suggest you cut my tweaked version of code right back to the basics, make sure you understand the fundamentals of KO, and then build it back up again. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, will try it and update this POST. but second drop down is not loading in your fiddle.I mean when I select one item in first drop down , it should refresh the items in second drop down. I have used  "subscribe" function.

Comment: Here's a quick hack to get the second drop down working - http://jsfiddle.net/sifriday/eu95b2mz/5/

Comment: I reckon you should take a good look at this example: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/collections.html and try rebuilding your code initially without the module pattern - just try it with a view-model for simplicity. It feels like you're getting in a tangle with the KO patterns because of code you don't need. For example, the second drop-down doesn't really need to come from a subscription, because the data is already in your view-model via the thing you selected in the first drop-down.

Comment: Yes I agree, i want to get rid of "subscribe" kind of code, I agree I have mixed up things here. Yes, second drop down values I should have taken from view model. As a beginner of KnockoutJS i ended up this code. meanwhile I also will try best from my side. my requirement is to send FINAL collection to database.Actually I have web API to get JSON data for drop downs and both drop down values are coming from different API. seems like I am complicating things.but in above POST i clubbed it into "sampleResourceViews" once i get it from 2 web api calls.

Comment: Your solution works but Kindly help me how can I achieve the same by simple view model approach. Because I need to send selected items in drop down to DB.